# Query / Filter woocommerce products by product type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I added new product type like [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120220/66786)

Now I want to show just that product type. Here is the my query:

```
$query_args = array('post_type' => 'product' );

$r = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $r->have_posts() ) { .........
```

How can I query only products of this new product type?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In WooCommerce, "post type" is a custom taxonomy, so you need to add [taxonomy parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to `WP_Query`.

```
$query_args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'your_type', 
        ),
    ),
 );
```

Where the `terms` argument is the same as in the `$this->product_type = 'your_type';` part of your new product type's class constructor.

Comment: I have custom data attributes in product datas. How can I use them in loop? How can I filter products with this attributes?

For example I have color and size data attributes. Now how can I the list red and large products?

Comment: You should ask your own question. Keep in mind that attributes are really just taxonomies, so you will need to make a more complex `tax_query` statement.

Comment: I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917231/how-to-use-woocommerce-data-attributes-in-the-loop and I tried a lot of combination but I didn't run it

Comment: sorry but only you answered this question I'm still working on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305733/filtering-with-woocommerce-data-attributes

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner way - use WooCommerce wc_get_products rather than just WP_Query.

```
$args = array(
    'type' => 'custom_product_type'
    );
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
```