# How to use woocommerce data attributes in the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom product type and custom loop for listing woocommerce products

```
$query_args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'custom_type', 
      ),
  ),
);

$r = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $r->have_posts() ) {
```

I have custom data attributes in product datas. How can I use them in loop? How can I filter products with this attributes?

For example I have color and size data attributes. Now how can I the list red and large products?

Comment: I believe you are trying to ask "how do I query products by their custom attributes?" If so, my answer below should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Attributes are just custom taxonomies. Keep in mind that the taxonomy name will always be the attribute name preceded by `pa_`.  This is just WooCommerce's naming convention to avoid conflicting taxonomy names. To query more than one taxonomy, see the "Multiple Taxonomy Handling" section in [WP Query Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters).

If, for example, you were trying to query products of product type = `custom_type` and color = `red` *and* a size attribute = `large`, your example args would look like this:

```
$query_args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'custom_type', 
      ),
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'red', 
      ),
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'pa_size',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'large', 
      ),
  ),
);
```