# Woocommerce - product attribute query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Does anyone know a way to query category archive page products by a range for a product attribute. The following works but this is because this is a custom field for a product as apposed to a product attribute which is stored as a taxonomy.

```
$meta_query[] = array(
    'key' => '_height',
    'value' => $_GET['min_height'],
    'compare' => '>='
  );
 $meta_query[] = array(
    'key' => '_height',
    'value' => $_GET['max_height'],
    'compare' => '<='
  );
```

Is it possible to achieve the above but with product attributes e.g pa_capacity etc.

I could create custom fields for all products from a selection of product attributes for a work around , but i would rather not do this as it is duplicate of content in attributes and custom fields. Although this would work as it has been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your on the correct path to the solution.
A smiliar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917231/how-to-use-woocommerce-data-attributes-in-the-loop).

Looks like WooCommerce works with taxonomies and terms instead of meta_keys.
Therefore, your query should look more like this-

```
$query_args = array(
 'post_type' => 'product',
 'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'custom_type', 
      ),
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'red', 
      ),
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'pa_size',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'large', 
      ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Not sure if this would work for a range based query like above? As the query above is using two values ,  I dont think this is possible with product attributes because they are taxonomies. The above works for getting products between two values e.g 100 - 200. I am trying to clarify if this is possible for product attributes as they are taxonomies compared to my question which uses custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP/MySQL query to implement the required filtrations

```
SELECT p.ID AS product_id,
       p.post_title AS product_name,
       t.term_id,
       tt.taxonomy AS attribute_name,
       t.`name` AS value_name,
       t.slug AS vlaue_slug
FROM wp_posts AS p,
     wp_terms AS t,
     wp_term_taxonomy AS tt,
     wp_term_relationships AS tr
WHERE tt.term_id = t.term_id
  AND p.ID = tr.`object_id`
  AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
  AND tt.taxonomy IN ('pa_height', 'pa_capacity')
  AND ((tt.taxonomy = 'pa_height'
        AND t.`name` >= 10
        AND t.`name` <= 100)
       OR (tt.taxonomy = 'pa_capacity'
           AND t.`name` >= 23))
  AND p.post_type = 'product'
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY p.post_title;
```

You can edit `('pa_height', 'pa_capacity')` with PHP and also it related values in where clause. The above query will return product_id(s) which can be passed through `wc_get_product()` and do your stuff.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there anyway to edit the current query as the code in my question is being run to edit the current query on the product archive page , by just adding new meta query conditions? Instead of having to rebuild the whole product query itself.